# AWS Kinesis Stream Consumer using Push or Pull Protocol?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

AWS Kinesis Stream Consumer is using which protocol? Push or Pull? Basically how the Kinesis Stream consumer being implemented? Does it maintain a long live connection to Kinesis Stream server using Push protocol? or using Pull protocol?

Answer (score 2):

It's pull.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/amazon-kinesis-consumers.html

Consumers read from the shards using the KCL via a shard iterator.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is both. My understanding is that you can use pull model if you get result using GetShardIteratorRequest. You can use push model if you get results using IRecordProcessor.
Example using push model:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/learning-kinesis-module-one-consumer.html

Example using pull model:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-sdk.html#kinesis-using-sdk-java-get-data